# Outputting HTML elements through WP-API

Tags: tags, encoding, wp-api

I am using WP-API to create a JavaScript app, where I am using http requests to pull content out of the WordPress database. For a regular post, I am not getting all element data that I expect.

I put the following text into the Visual Editor.

> Detectives are investigating the horrific murder of a woman amid claims that the suspected killer was trying to eat her.
>
> The 22-year-old woman is known to have been bitten and suffered terrible facial injuries in the shocking incident at a hostel for homeless people in south Wales.
>
> But some neighbours of the hostel have also claimed the suspected attacker, who died after police fired a Taser at him, subjected the woman to an act of cannibalism.
>
> Gwent police are refusing to comment on the claims. However, a source with knowledge of the investigation said that cannibalism was now a line of inquiry.

I request the posts through the API, get them, but expect to get content with p tags at the start and end of each paragraph. Instead I get this:

```
"content": "Detectives are investigating the horrific murder of a woman amid claims that the suspected killer was trying to eat her.\r\n\r\nThe 22-year-old woman is known to have been bitten and suffered terrible facial injuries in the shocking incident at a hostel for homeless people in south Wales.\r\n\r\nBut some neighbours of the hostel have also claimed the suspected attacker, who died after police fired a Taser at him, subjected the woman to an act of cannibalism.\r\n\r\nGwent police are refusing to comment on the claims. However, a source with knowledge of the investigation said that cannibalism was now a line of inquiry.",
```

Is my problem with the WordPress editor, or encoding? I am more of a JavaScript programmer and using WordPress for the first time because I wanted a simple interface for the client.

Comment: I realised my mistake. The following line in my functions.php:

   `~remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

This was in the WordPress underscore empty template which I started the project with, and was removing html from the content.

Answer (score 1):

I realised my mistake. The following line in my functions.php:

`~remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

This was in the WordPress underscore empty template which I started the project with, and was removing html from the content.